# Using "let" in imperative sentence

Tags: imperatives, question-tags

Which one is correct?

> - Don't let us stay here,  will you?
> - Don't let us stay here, shall we?

I have chosen the first one because "let" is used here as "allow" but my colleague made me confused

Comment: Both are equally correct, but neither is idiomatic, and neither says what you want to say. As Robusto recommends, say "Let's not stay here" and leave it at that. Do not add a question tag. That makes no sense at all. *No matter what the tag is.*

Comment: What is the context? Who are you talking to, and what are you trying to say? The first sounds like you're asking someone to prohibit you from staying here.

Comment: Neither one makes any sense at all.

Comment: @HotLicks The first one makes some sense as it stands (at least in British English) but I would expect to see the second turned around a little to become "Let's not stay here shall we?". In both cases a negative Trip Advisor post seems to be called for.

Comment: The first sentence sounds ok because the subject here is clearly 'you'.  In the second, what's the role 'we' which is supposedly the object?

Comment: The only reasonable follow-up question (hardly a tag) to "Let's not stay here" is something along the lines of "You can't seriously be thinking of doing so?" (and it would probably have an exclamation mark rather than a question mark).

Comment: Something like "Don't let us stay here, right?" or "Don't let us stay here, OK?" would be possible. I guess this is part of an exercise involving tag questions, or the OP had just learnt about English tag questions.

Comment: *Don't let's* means (in some dialects) *let's not*. But you cannot expand it to *Do not let's*.

Answer (score 1):

"Don't let us" in that sense is a BrE way of saying "Let's not." It's not really imperative, but is more of an entreaty.

Usually you hear it in contracted form:

> Don't let's tell Andrew about this anytime soon.

Comment: Ok, what about "Don't let me go, shall I ?/ will you?

Comment: Those things don't really work together. Certainly "shall I" doesn't work. If you say "Don't let me go" it means "Keep holding on to me"; You might find a way to wedge the idea of "will you" into that, but I really don't see it happening.

Comment: You would seem to know more about idiomatic usage here in the UK than I do. Though [Google data](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=GIl8WqOOH4eCgAaizZyAAQ&q=%22don%27t+let+us+stay+here%22+-%22you+don%27t+let+us+stay+here%22&oq=%22don%27t+let+us+stay+here%22+-%22you+don%27t+let+us+stay+here%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20837.27623.0.28092.7.7.0.0.0.0.87.395.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.152...33i22i29i30k1.0.i7kkudyMDjc) is more in line with my opinion.

Comment: @Edwin: I didn't see you express an opinion here.

Comment: ["Don't let us stay here"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=bLR8WsH3IIfGgAaLwbKICw&q=%22don%27t+let+us+stay+here%22+-%22you+don%27t+let+us+stay+here%22+-%22they+don%27t+let+us+stay+here%22&oq=%22don%27t+let+us+stay+here%22+-%22you+don%27t+let+us+stay+here%22+-%22they+don%27t+let+us+stay+here%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...25573.32233.0.32654.9.9.0.0.0.0.104.525.8j1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.2PkPad9fXR0) 6 -

Comment: ["let's not stay here"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=jbR8Wr_UKpW9gAbeup-ABg&q=%22let%27s+not+stay+here%22&oq=%22let%27s+not+stay+here%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...54420.64111.0.64781.18.18.0.0.0.0.172.1584.14j4.18.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.17.1508...0i7i10i30k1j0i10i30k1j0i8i10i30k1j0i8i30k1j0i7i30k1j0i67k1j0i7i5i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i8i7i10i30k1.0.c6fWEs5VRUM) 24 000 reflects my opinion precisely.

Comment: 1872? I had no idea publications of that era still had such currency today.

Comment: This has turned up again. // Search data for "Don't let us stay here" -Dahomey -lyrics soon corrects to 20 Google hits, mostly false positives like "They don't let us stay here". This usage may have been more common in British novels of the 1930s, but even if so it _doesn't have much currency today_.

Answer (score -1):

Well it depends on what you are trying to say, if you are using imperative you dont have to use the "will you" at the end, because is an imperative order!

is not like saying: "it´s a beautiful day, isn´t it?"

And about "Don't let us stay here, shall we? "

You are ordering someone to not let us (we) stay here, shall we is used to talk about when we are part of the group of people you are talking about.

Example: "Let´s go to the mall, shall we?"